# mySQL view derived from multiple tables with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

How would I code the query to yield the mySQL VIEW 'inventory' below from the following 3 mySQL tables:

Table: **product**

```
product_id    category_id   brand
 1              1            Aylmer
 2              2            Ace
 3              2            Weston
 4              1            Campbell
 5              3            Vachon
 6              4            Hero
 7              5            Lactancia
 8              4            Welch
 9              4            Bonne Maman
10              4            Smucker
```

Table: **category**

```
category_id   name_en   name_fr
     1         soup     soupe
     2         bread    pain
     3         cake     gateau
     4         jam      confiture
     5         butter   beurre
```

Table: **other_name**

```
other_name_id    category_id     alternate_category
      1               1                 broth
      2               1                 stock
      3               2                 roll
      4               2                 bun
      5               2                 loaf
      6               4                 sweet spread
      7               5                 salty spread
```

View: **inventory**

```
product_id   name_en     name_fr      brand       alternate_categories      
       1       soup       soupe       Aylmer        broth; stock
       2       bread      pain        Ace           roll; bun; loaf
       3       bread      pain        Weston        roll; bun; loaf
       4       soup       soupe       Campbell      broth; stock
       5       cake       gateau      Vachon        
       6       jam        confiture   Hero          sweet spread
       7       butter     beurre      Lactancia     salty spread
       8       jam        confiture   Welsh         sweet spread
       9       jam        confiture   Bonne Maman   sweet spread
      10       jam        confiture   Smucker       sweet spread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple query with join and some aggregation

```
select p.product_id,
c.name_en,
c.name_fr,
p.brand,
group_concat(o.alternate_category separator '; ') alternate_categories
from product p
join category c on(p.category_id = c.category_id)
join other_name o on (c.category_id = o.category_id)
group by p.product_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef2f24d/2)

Comment: Khalid, I just noticed that your suggestion did not return a product_id where no matching other_name_id was found. In other words, product_id = 5 of the 'inventory' view above was not returned. It seems like Outer Join might do the trick, but that didn't work. Any follow-up suggestions?

Comment: @JamesScott yes you are right left join will give you the results where no associations are present